# Using javascript to modify html element and create new element

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below piece of code

```
<input type="text" />
<button> Submit </button>
```

Now, when the user types some input and clicks on the submit button, I want the input text to become non-editable but the text should still be there.Also, the submit button should dissapear. Moreover, below the input text box, i want to creat another input text with the similar to the original one with a submit button. So, this is somethings like a commenting system. Any idea on how to do this using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" />
<button> Submit </button>


$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('input').prop('disabled', true);
})
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dDk5D/)

Comment: I want a text box, not div . Second, after clicking submit, another similar thing should appear after it

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to do this is below. For unobtrusive Javascript, however, you should bind the `onclick` event to the button programmatically. Or better yet, use jQuery, which always abstracts events, which is why we love it so.

```
 <script>
 function disableInput() {
  document.getElementById("foo").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("bar").style.display = "none";
 }
 </script>

<input id="foo" type="text" value="Some Text" />
<button id="bar" onclick="disableInput();"> Submit </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vT33V/2/)

If you will be duplicating content be sure to remove id's. They must be unique per page. Here is the html:

```
<p class="comment">
  <input type="text" value="Initial Text" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</p>
```

Using jQuery we bind to all future buttons using `live`. When the button is clicked, clone the row, disable the field, and remove the button. Finally re-insert the cloned paragraph after this one:

```
// Execute when document is ready
$(function() {
  // Bind click handler to all current and future button elements
  $('.comment button').live('click', function() {
    // Find the paragraph this button is in and clone it
    var p = $(this).closest('p'), 
        row = p.clone();

    // Disable text field
    $(this).prev().attr('disabled',true);

    // Hide submit button for this row
    $(this).hide();

    // Insert a new field/button pair below this one
    p.after(row);
  }); 
});
```